# Upload video to SharePoint library by code

Tags: development, document-library, file-upload, video

I am making a app for SharePoint and have a form with several inputs for text and for files as well. The input for files works fine for regular files such as Word, Excel, PowerPoint, images etc... but wont work with videos. Is it possible to upload a video to a document library by code? Or cant you do that simply because the files is usually to big and would take long to upload?

The files is of the type `HttpPostedFileBase` and sent by a normal mvc form.

And this is the code for uploading it to the folder

```
FileCreationInformation attachFileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
attachFileInfo.ContentStream = pNewRequest.FileToUpload1.InputStream;
attachFileInfo.Url = Path.GetFileName(pNewRequest.FileToUpload1.FileName);
newFolder.Files.Add(attachFileInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

On this page there's a comprehensive list on methods to upload files to SharePoint online using CSOM: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint

It show guidance on when to use a certain method.

Answer (score 0):

If the video file is very large, then it is recommended to upload via "StartUpload","ContinueUpload","FinishUpload" with chunkedfiles to achieve:

[Large file upload in SharePoint Online with CSOM PowerShell](https://gist.github.com/asadrefai/ecfb32db81acaa80282d)

[SharePoint Online/2016/2013 - How To Upload Large Files Using PowerShell Automation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online20162013-how-to-upload-large-files-using-powershell-automati/)